# Android Service Activity Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to pass a string from activiy to service.

```
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putString("MyString", string);
            mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
            startService(mIntent);
```

this is in Activity class

```
            Intent myIntent = getIntent();
            String value = myIntent.getExtras().getString(key);
```

and this is in Service class
It doesn't accept getIntent() method :S I don't know what I'll do

Answer (score 1):

The code in the service must be placed in `onStart(Intent intent, int startid)` method and the code becomes `String value = intent.getExtras().getString(key);`

Answer (score 0):

When you start the service using `startService(mIntent)` the service's [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) is called which is good place to handle the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Move the part of your code that depends on the intent to onStartCommand: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)

OnStartCommand was called OnStart before api version 5, follow link to documentation for further information about backwards compatibility in your app.

```
@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      String value = intent.getExtras().getString(key);
  }
```

Also remember to move heavy code into a background thread that you start in onStartCommand, as otherwise you will run into an Application Not Responding error.